# How do you import a category defined within it's parent class in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c-category

I have a category following the format below, designed to encapsulate simplistic methods only necessary because they will be changed by children classes. How do I import this category into other classes, such as `ClassOneTests.m`, `ClassOneA.h, .m` and `ClassOneB.h, .m`?
`#import "ClassOne+MyCategory.h"` gives an error.

**ClassOne.m**

```
#import "ClassOne.h"

@interface ClassOne ()
-(void)MethodOne
@end

@interface ClassOne (MyCategory)
-(NSString *)servantToMethodOne
@end

@implementation ClassOne
-(void)MethodOne {
[self servantToMethodOne];
...
}
@end

@implementation ClassOne (MyCategory)
...
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to separate the category interface into **ClassOne.h** and leave the imports as they are.